# Calculation of relay isolation

Tags: relay, resistance, isolation, resistivity

I am trying to calculate isolation of an relay in ohm. Can it be approached as calculation of resistance of solid materials?

$$
R_{air} = ρ_{air} * \frac{d_{gap}}{A_{contact}}
$$

Let's say resistivity of air equals 3.3e^15 Ωm and gap is 1mm between contacts with area of 1mm^2. As a result we get 3.3e^12. Can this be an approximate value to real isolation value?

Thank you.

Additional information:
frequency range is from DC to 5GHz. Load voltage Vp is 24 and current is 20mA.

Comment: It can be an approximate value yes.

Comment: Depends. "Isolation" may refer to isolation at DC, or a range of RF frequencies in general, or at a specific RF frequency. Your answer is good at DC.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. @BrianDrummond what should be the strategy for RF frequencies? Could you give a hint?

Comment: I only commented to avoid the trap of thinking a DC solution applied at high frequencies and finding out later, perhaps expensively, it doesn't. As a first step, I'd add that missing information to the question including the frequency range, power level, and characteristic impedance you're interested in.

Comment: I added some more details.

Comment: What's your goal here?  Any relay for 5 GHz would be a highly specialized device; you wouldn't try to evaluate it from first principles but rather by reading the data sheet or using a suitable network analyzer.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I don't have a relay, however the goal is finding out a satisfactory method to estimate dimensions of a deliberately left air gap between two contacts a relay.

Comment: But why would you want to do any such thing or use a relay (at the very least not a professionally designed and well proven and data-sheet-characterized one) for such an extreme application?  Your question does not make any sense at all.  You also appear to be confusing *conduction* and *coupling* issues.

Comment: Sometimes isolation may refer to the allowable potential between the switched circuit and the coil. Rather than the resistance across open circuit terminals (which is what you seem to be trying to calculate).

Answer (score 0):

A better model of the "isolation" is to view the air_gap as part of voltage_divider.

The other part of the voltage divider is a parallel RC: the total capacitance on the node susceptible to interference, PLUS the resistance of that node.

The resistance defines the corner frequency of the builtin HIgh Pass filter, which causes **ZERO RESPONSE AT DC**.

At high frequencies, above the HPF corner frequency, your isolation is accurately computed as the ratio of the 2 capacitances.